# Javascript parsing String to int automatically

Tags: javascript

I'm calling a JavaScript function from an onclick event in a JSP page.

```
    <%
       String value = "06654"
    %>

  <body>
   <a href="javascript://" onclick="myFunction(<%= value %>)">Click Me!</a>
  </body>
```

My JavaScript function is like this

```
    function myFunction(myString)
   {
      alert(myString);
      //Do Stuff;
   }
```

myString is equal to 06654 but I'm getting 6654 when I alerts it's value. How do I stop js from automatically parsing the String to an int?

Comment: It does not do that automatically (unless you are using `myString` with operators that work on numbers). You must be processing the argument you pass to `myFunction` somehow.

Comment: It doesn't do that automatically, I still get the '0' here: http://jsfiddle.net/53v3y/

Comment: What are you passing to myFunction? It must be an int. call toString on whatever you are passing to it.

Comment: What could be the reason for it then? The value (06654) shows up fine in the html source but when javascript reads it it truncates it to 6654

Comment: Can you post above how you actually call this function? That would make this a lot easier.

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon I've tried that but no luck. It's really weird, the html source reads the myString value right

Comment: @Shile: You are probably doing more than just reading the value from the DOM. If you'd provide the relevant part of your actual code, we could help you more.

Comment: I've updated the original post with how the function is called.

Comment: Have a look at the **generated** source. If the value you pass to `myFunction` is not enclosed in quotes, it will be interpreted as number. You probably want `myFunction('<%= value %>')`. Strings are delimited by quotation marks in JavaScript (as in many other languages). Be aware that some part of the code (`<%= ... %>`) runs on the **server** and its **output** is then evaluated by the client.

Comment: @FelixKling Aaaah! I overlooked that part.. Works perfectly now, THANKS!

Comment: @FelixKling, why there's no "this comment should be an answer" flag?

Comment: @Oleg: Maybe they think people are not that crazy and provide answers in comments... muahahaha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you output the string into the page, the result will be

```
… onclick="myFunction(06654)" …
```

which is obviosly interpreted as a number. To make it a JavaScript string, put quotes around it:

```
… onclick="myFunction('<%= value %>')" …
```